# aligning an image and label in a div

Tags: html, css, cordova, alignment

I have a label and an image in a div which acts as a navbar in a mobile app. I need the text to be centred and the image to be on the right. I can't manage to get the right combination. Code here:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <div class="centered">
         <img src="../images/culogo50x40.png" alt="logo" height="25px" class="c1">
         <h3>Login</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

In class centred, I have:

```
.centered { 
width: 100%;
height: auto; 
position: fixed; 
top: 20%; 
background-color: red;
text-align:center; 
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

and in class c1, I have:

```
img.c1 {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) may be appreciated.

Comment: As suggested above, a fiddle will be helpful and are you supporting IE8?

Comment: So what is the problem http://jsfiddle.net/fqqzab2o/?

Comment: I would have recommended vertical-align:middle. But seeing position fixed there, not sure if that's the case.

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kjjy4fu/) explain whats your problem.

Comment: Do you need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4kjjy4fu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can `position` your `img` `absolute` and make the `right:0;` to float it right. To make it vertical middle just make the following changes to your style

```
img.c1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4kjjy4fu/3/)**

NOTE: `margin:auto` works only with either fixed `width` or `height` to your element.

Comment: I replaced my img.c1 css with yours and I'm still having the same issue. The word login is almost centred but the image puts it off slightly

Comment: Do you have any screen shot or reference for that i don't exactly whats going around there with you